# Return void or any other type with Typescript

Tags: typescript

Can i do this ? its possible ?
If no, has an alternative method to do this ?

```js
ngOnInit():  void | Observable<TModel> {
//return bla bla bla 
}
```

Comment: When i use this in visual studio 2015, have a error that 'ngOnInit().subscribe()' does not exist on type void, but  the ngOnInit() method return is 'void | Observable<TModel>' and subscribe() is a method from Observable. If i want use this, need to do a cast '(ngOnInit() as Observable<any>).subscribe()'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

An alternative is to have a return type of `Observable<TModel> | undefined`, which will work well with strict null checks:

```
function myFunction(): string | undefined {
    return Math.random() < 0.5 ? "" : undefined;
}

const myString = myFunction();
myString.charAt(0);  // error
myString!.charAt(0); // ok

if (typeof myString === "string") {
    myString.charAt(0); // ok
}
```

Comment: Good job guy, i did not remembered of the '!' operator. This go help me very much, thank you!